# Canvas browsers support using easeljs?

Tags: createjs

As I am converting my flash based virtual lab to HTML5 using EaseLJS, I thought its a good idea to ask if some one knows any browser support issues or restrictions? lots of new and old browsers out there ..

I wonder how easeljs handle such diversity, is there a known-compatibility-issues of easeljs APIs ?

A matrix would be perfect! well ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Canvas is a pretty well-supported and consistent HTML5 feature - and there are very few inconsistencies between the major browsers. There are some touch issues on some of the mobile platforms that we are working to address - mainly Android.

Cheers.